# read complete url using nginx and lua

Tags: nginx, lua

I have a URL that reads as below

```
test.com/#/country/a1
```

Using ngx.var.request_uri, I am only able to read the `'/' but not '/#/country/a1'`

How can I get lua to read the full URL?

Thanks.

Comment: How do you request the URL? A web browser will cut off everything starting with the `#` and treat everything after that as an id/anchor on the page to scroll to – and the server will only see `GET / HTTP/1.1`.

Comment: Thanks @nobody , this is initiated from a client action. I intend to read the country value and apply a redirection to the appropriate site.